# Why files disappear when using autofs

Tags: linux, nfs, autofs

I have a disk mount as /local in the centos 5.3.
Under /local/foldera/folderb/ I have lots of folders like：

```
drwxrwxrwx root root 4096 DEC 10 10:40 Platformxx
```

Then I've build another server and on ther server many Platform like on the above.I want to use autofs to automatically mount those folders to my server through nfs.Just use mount command everything works fine.Then i choose to use the autofs.In /etc/auto.master I write like this:

```
/local/foldera/folderb /etc/auto.nfs
```

and at the /etc/auto.nfs:

```
Platformxx -rw,soft xx.xx.xx.xx:/xx/Platformxx
```

After config that,server autofs reload.When I open every folder in folderb. Error tells me the system cannot find the folder.And i cannot see anything in the folderb.The command 'll' returns total 0. After i delete the record i added to auto.master and reboot the server, those folders come back.
So what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You see an expected behavior. If you want to see the folders with "ls /local/foldera/folderb", use the `--ghost` option in auto.master:

```
/local/foldera/folderb  /etc/auto.nfs    --ghost
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update, the `--ghost` option has been deprecated and it has been replaced by `browse` - [source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/auto.master.5.html)

```
              [no]browse
                     This is an autofs specific option that is a pseudo
                     mount option and so is given without a leading
                     dash. Use of the browse option pre-creates mount
                     point directories for indirect mount maps so the
                     map keys can be seen in a directory listing without
                     being mounted. Use of this option can cause
                     performance problem if the indirect map is large so
                     it should be used with caution. The internal
                     program default is to enable browse mode for
                     indirect mounts but the default installed
                     configuration overrides this by setting BROWSE_MODE
                     to "no" because of the potential performance
                     problem. This option does the same as the
                     deprecated --ghost option, the browse option is
                     preferred because it is used by other autofs
                     implementations.
```